# Upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 does not proceed

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, do-release-upgrade, mythbuntu

I ran `do-release-upgrade --mode=desktop` on my Xenial i386 machine on which Mythbuntu was originally installed.

It proceeds to "Updating repository information", but /etc/apt/sources.list does not change. I have waited for several minutes. How long one would have to wait for such a change? What is wrong with the upgrade process?

Comment: Several minutes may not be long enough.  I can't recall how long it took last time I release-upgraded, but I would have given it a lot longer than that before I was worried..

Comment: @guiverc true, it took longer to proceed.